# Rebase onto Rebase/Squash

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

This is a common situation I come across, and I'm looking for a clean solution.

1. Do some work on a git branch (`my-first-work`)
2. Push up to github
3. Start a new branch (`some-further-work`), based on top of the work `my-first-work`

*Unspecified amount of time passes*

4. Approver rebases or squashes `my-first-work` onto `master`
5. This creates new commits that git doesn't treat as equivalent to the stuff I'm based on, even though the end result is identical (i.e. the head of `master` is identical to the head of `my-first-work`)
6. I run `git rebase master` to move `some-further-work` onto `master`
7. The commits from `my-first-work` that I'm based on now all conflict with what's already been squash/merged

Currently, I get around this by using `git rebase -i master` and then removing all the commits up to the head of `my-first-work`. This replays the additional commits cleanly on top of `master`.

Is there a cleaner solution? And is there a way to make git automatically recognise when a rebase/squash (as in 4) has occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cleaner* is in the eye (or hands?) of the beholder / worker, but you can use `git rebase --onto` to separate out *which commits to copy* from *where to put the copies*.

Remember that `git rebase` means:<sup>1</sup> *I have a linear chain of commits as shown in drawing 1, that I would like to copy to a new linear chain of commits as shown in drawing 2.  Once the copies are done I'd like my branch name to point to the last copied commit.  The original `A-B-C` chain is no longer useful even if it's still there.*

```
[drawing 1]
...--o--*--o   <-- upstream/master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- topic

[drawing 2]
...--o--*--o   <-- upstream/master
            \
             A'-B'-C'  <-- topic
```

The differences between the original commits and the copies are that the originals are based on commit `*`, which *was* the tip of `upstream/master` before.  The copies are based on the (new) tip of `upstream/master`.  The phrase *based on* here has literally two meanings: the *parent of* commit `A` is commit `*` but the *parent of* commit `A'` is the later commit, and the *snapshot in* commit `A` is `*`-plus-some-changes while the *snapshot in* commit `A'` adds the *same* changes to the *later* commit.

Since we use our shiny new commit `A'` (which has a different hash) in favor of the old dull `A`, we then need to copy `B` to `B'`, and `C` to `C'`, and once we are done we need our name `topic` to point not to `C` but to the last copied commit, `C'`.

Plain old `git rebase` does exactly this.  We say:

```
git checkout topic; git rebase upstream/master
```

which tells Git:

1. *Enumerate all the commits starting from `C` and working backwards.*  That's `C` then `B` then `A` then `*` then everything before `*`.
2. *Enumerate all the commits starting from `upstream/master` and working backwards.*  That's the second `o`, then `*` and then everything before `*`.
3. *Knock everything in the* second *list out of the* first *list.*  So that knocks out `*` and all the earlier commits.  The second `o` isn't in the first list, but that's OK: we'd knock it out if it *were* in, but it's not so we do nothing.  Our list now goes `C`, `B`, and `A`.
4. *Reverse the list to put it into the right order, then, one at a time, copy each commit to the new place.  The new place starts at the commit to which `upstream/master` points.*  So this copies `A` to `A'`, `B` to `B'`, and `C` to `C'`.
5. *Peel the current branch name `topic` off its previous location, and stick it on the new chain of commits, at the end as usual.*  So this makes `topic` point to `C'` instead of to `C`.

In your new case, though, you had:

```
...--o--*   <-- upstream/master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature1
                 \
                  D--E--F--G   <-- feature2
```

They, in their upstream, didn't take your `A-B-C` chain.  Instead, they made their own different `ABC` squash commit.  You grabbed it from the upstream repository, so you now have:

```
...--o--*--ABC   <-- upstream/master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature1
                 \
                  D--E--F--G   <-- feature2
```

If you just run `git checkout feature2; git rebase upstream/master`, your Git will enumerate commits `G-F-E-D-C-B-A-*-...`, enumerate `ABC-*-...`, subtract the second from the first, and be left with instructions to copy the `G-F-E-D-C-B-A` chain.

The fancier rebase command is:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto upstream/master feature1
```

What this does is separate the *target* argument—the place where Git will start the copying—from the *limit* argument.  The *target* is now `upstream/master` (the Git documentation calls this the *onto* argument).  The *limiting* argument is now `feature1`.  You can use the raw hash ID of commit `C` if you prefer.  Git just needs to know: *Where do I start my knock-out-these-commits enumeration?*  (Confusingly, the Git documentation calls this the *upstream* argument.)

As you can see, this now knocks out the `C-B-A-*` commits rather than just the `*` commit, so that after the copy, you have:

```
               D'-E'-F'-G'  [in progress]
              /
...--o--*--ABC   <-- upstream/master
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature1
                 \
                  D--E--F--G   <-- feature2
```

and now Git can peel the label `feature2` off `G` and stick it on `G2` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, there's quite a lot more to `git rebase`, especially now with the fancy new `--rebase-merges` option.  This *I have a linear chain of commits* is still its *main* use, though.

As a nice bonus, rebase can usually tell if they've taken your `A-B-C` chain and copied it to their own `A'-B'-C'` chain.  But that's just *usually*.  Rebase can *never* tell that they've taken your `A-B-C` and squashed it into their own `ABC`, so for that case you're stuck with `--onto`.

Comment: Fantastic. Really clear answer and a great explanation.